# Gnome Terminal ignores default profile size

Tags: 12.10, gnome, gnome-terminal

I am using Gnome 3.6 Ubuntu 12.10 kernel 3.5. My problem is that I have my default profile for gnome terminal set to 80x43. However, most of the time when launching Gnome terminal from the launcher, it defaults to some slightly smaller size (row-wise). It maintains the correct column width, but instead of 43 rows tall, it's something smaller (about 38-40). The confusing parts are:
1) It sometimes opens with the correct terminal size.
2) It always opens to the correct terminal size when I create a new window while within Gnome terminal.

Any ideas as to this inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that running gnome-terminal via the launcher looks at gnome-terminal's .desktop file in /usr/share/applications.
To test this, copy the relevant `.desktop` file to ~/.local/share/applications. Then, open the copied file in gedit, no need of sudo, and look at the line that starts with `Exec=`. Insert `--geometry 80x43` after `gnome-terminal` leaving a single space. Save the file. Close it and try running gnome-terminal from the launcher again.
I can't test this since I don't have gnome-terminal installed but nothing destructive can happen. If it doesn't work as desired, just delete the copied file and the launcher will then use the original file in `/usr/share/applications`.